# Git not pushing .bat files

Tags: git

I do not (as far as I know) have a .gitignore file setup in my local repo, but when I commit and push (even after doing git add --all) the repo doesn't push .bat files (and several other file types). I am using Git bash with Windows.

commands I am using:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "next commit here" .
git push -u origin master
git pull
```

Comment: Could you post the content of .gitignore file?

Comment: I don't believe I have one..... I definitely did not create one intentionally

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you are trying to troubleshoot Git ignores, the [`check-ignore` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) is useful:

> For each pathname given via the command-line or from a file via `--stdin`, show the pattern from .gitignore (or other input files to the exclude mechanism) that decides if the pathname is excluded or included. Later patterns within a file take precedence over earlier ones.

I recommend pointing this at your problematic files with the `--verbose` / `-v` flag, e.g.

```
git check-ignore --verbose path/to/file.bat
```

You should either get output like

```
.gitignore:5:*.bat   path/to/file.bat
```

indicating, in this case, that your file is ignored by the pattern `*.bat` found on line 5 of the file `.gitignore`, or no output and a return value of 1, indicating that the file is not ignored.

Be careful running this against multiple files at once; if even one of them is ignored you will get a successful return value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have a global .gitignore file. Check this for details:
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Answer (score 0):

Please type: "git add ." and later "git status" check if your *.bat files are visible and marked with green color. If there are not visible that means that *.bat extension is added to gitignore and should be removed from there.